# How to ignore the ./ characters in the file location?

Tags: bash, shell

I run the following command to get the location of a .sh file and store it in a variable:

```
startupfile=`find . -name "startup.sh"`
```

The result of the above is:

```
./server1/bin/startup.sh
```

The next step is to run the `startup.sh` file.

When I try `sh $startupfile`, it fails to run the server.

Is there a way to ignore the `./` in the location value? Any other way to run the startup.sh script.

Comment: Why would “ignoring the `./`” help?

Comment: Is it me, or did the edit fix the bug?

Comment: @ams The edit hasn't changed anything apart from the formatting.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it fails to run the server'?  What error are you getting?  Is it possible that you need to use `bash "$startupfile"` rather than using `sh`?

Comment: @devnull, yours didn't, but the first edit added backticks.

Comment: @ams No, that too didn't _add_ those.  The [source](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9e0738f6-f4d9-43e9-9264-14c3963fa33f/view-source) would reveal that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
startupfile=$(find . -name "startup.sh")
```

OR less preferred in BASH:

```
startupfile=`find . -name "startup.sh"`
```

This is called [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)

**UPDATE:: Post question edit:**

To avoid running the script with full path you can place path of `startup.sh` in your PATH variable, so something like this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
 export PATH=$PATH:~/server1/binripts
```

Then you can run:

```
startup.sh
```

From anywhere your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

The `./` is harmless.

You have another problem. Did you change directory between the two commands? Is the "script" not actually a valid script?

Answer (score 0):

The `./` is not the problem, it is simply a (superfluous) path to the current directory: `./file` and `././././file` are both valid paths to `file` in the current directory, the number of leading `./`'s doesn't make any difference.

Looking at the source of your original question (before it was edited for better formatting), there were single quotes `'` around the command: `'sh $startupfile'`. If you had those in the actual command as well, that is your problem; the command should be: `sh "$startupfile"`.

Other than that, it's hard to tell what the problem might be. Check that `echo "$startupfile"` shows the correct path and *only* the correct path. If it does, does `sh ./server1/bin/startup.sh` work? If not, what is the error?

Comment: 'sh ./server1/bin/startup.sh ' does not work. Its a server startup file. The server fails to start. I want the command to be 'sh /server1/bin/startup.sh'

Comment: @DeeptiK Even without the ' quotes? Does `sh server1/bin/startup.sh` work, then, or why did you assume that the `./` is at fault? What does `ls -l server1/bin/startup.sh` say, does the file exist and do you have read permissions to it?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific questions:

*Is there a way to ignore the ./ in the location value?*

There are a couple of ways of stripping off leading directory names.  The most efficient, though most obscure is:

```
startupfile=${startupfile##*/}
```

That removes the longest string on the left ending in '/'.  The second way is a little more obvious, but involves creating a child process:

```
startupfile=$(basename "$startupfile")
```

*Any other way to run the startup.sh script.*

Yes, you could use the `PATH` environment variable, as @anubhava said.  The only thing I would add is that you need execute access on the script; `chmod u+x "$startupfile"`.

However, the implication of the name "startupfile" is that it is doing some sort of initialisation, in which case you might need to run it in the *same* process using the `source` or `.`(dot) command:

```
source "$startupfile"
```

You might still need the path in the filename, or update `PATH`.